# Where are the Shrinkster short URL codes now?

Tags: url-shortening

[Shrinkster.com](http://www.shrinkster.com/) has stated for a while: *We'll be back soon! We are temporarily offline due to abuse by spammers.* unless I just stumbled upon this temp message twice in the span of a year or so.

Does anybody know:

- if it will come back online to make its URLs available?
- or if the existing short URL codes were transferred to another service?

I realize the domain itself was not transferred (thus the message) but I would think the unique short codes should at least be transferred.  Maybe shrinkster.com should move its domain to an active URL shortening service so old podcasts, etc will still have relevant links.

Comment: Apparently it is coming back. Referenced in the introduction here: https://www.dotnetrocks.com/?show=1769

Answer (score 2):

<sup>That's why the short urls are breaking the Internet :) When they are down half of the Internet is returning 404s.</sup>

*Due to abuse by spammers*, could be anything. They might have lost their database for example or they might just got too much traffic and the servers went down. Nobody really knows. I would suggest you to use something that is [more stable, most secure and fastest](http://techcrunch.com/2010/09/30/googlegoo-gl-is-a-go-the-stablest-most-secure-and-fastest-url-shortener-on-the-web/). The URL shortener by Google: [goo.gl](http://goo.gl).